# Translate to SQL Failed Error in Entity Framework When Filtering on Nullable Navigation Property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Having issues with ef core failing to translate conditions on nullable navigation properties

I was writing a filter for an endpoint and noticed something strange.

```
var employeeOnServices = await _context.ServiceRecords
    .Where(x=>x.Employees != null)
    .Where(x=> x.Status == ServiceStatusEnum.InProgress
        || x.Status == ServiceStatusEnum.OnHold)
    .Select(x =>x.Employees.Select(y=>y.Id))
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

When i run the above code piece, i get translate to sql failed error, when i remove

`.Where(x=>x.Employees != null)`

code works fine. Employees has many to many relation with ServiceRecords table but as far as i can see relations are nullable on their classes.

Thank you

Comment: Without having tested, I suspect that it's because it's a collection property rather than a singular. The question is not whether that collection is `null` but whether it is empty. Try changing `x.Employees != null` to `x.Employees.Any()` and see whether that works.

Comment: There's no problem with nullable properties. You're dealing with tables, not objects. You don't have to check for null at all. Post the actual full exception text. I'd expect `.Select(x =>x.Employees.Select(y=>y.Id))` to throw. If you want to flatten a list, use `SelectMany`

Comment: What are the actual entities? If  you want to avoid duplicate Employee IDs you should start from Employees, not ServiceRecords, eg `context.Employees.Where(e=>statusList.Contains(e.ServiceRecord.Status)).Select(e=>e.Id)`. That's equivalent to a `SELECT ID FROM Employees WHERE EXISTS  (....)`  query.

Comment: Did you tried with `.Include(...)`?

Comment: @user16606026, remember `Include` with `Select` has no sense. It is completely ignored by EF.

Answer (score 2):

Collection navigations should always be non-nullable. You should be able to achieve what you want by seeing if it an empty collection:

```
var employeeOnServices = await _context.ServiceRecords
    .Where(x=>x.Employees.Any())
    .Where(x=> x.Status == ServiceStatusEnum.InProgress
              || x.Status == ServiceStatusEnum.OnHold)
    .Select(x =>x.Employees.Select(y=>y.Id))
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: `.Any()` is preferable to `.Count() > 0`. The former will short-circuit as soon as any item is found, whereas the latter first has to count all items and then check whether that number is greater than zero. The latter is particularly bad for large collections.

Comment: edited to replace count with any